# How to detect doors and windows from a floor plan image?

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I am working on floor plan analysis where I want to detect the number of doors and windows in floor plan images. How can I pull this off using OpenCV in Python?

I have already tried detecting walls in the images and below is the code for the same.

```
img_bw = 255*(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) > 20).astype('uint8')

se1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
se2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,1))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(img_bw, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, se1)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, se2)

mask = np.dstack([mask, mask, mask]) / 255
out = img * mask
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.imshow(out, cmap="gray")
```

Now I am looking to extract the number of doors and windows (probably in CSV or XML sheet).

[image]

Comment: Where is your sample image?

Comment: @BahramdunAdil I have edited the question with a sample image. Please have a look.

Comment: I think you should try to train a DNN model using TF or some other framework, be careful to label the images very very correctly. So you can give a try to DNN and see the result, I think It will work, otherwise, I did not any better solution to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on a similar project. You could absolutely train a neural network or svm. But I think you can solve the issue by instead using several filters and save yourself some time.

In my project I've done just that but for smaller floorplans than your example floorplan above. So if you just copy some code from my repo and change thresholds it should work.

The image below visualizes the current result of my project detection on your example floorplan:

Color explanation:
MarineBlue - Outercontour,
Blue - Walls,
Yellow - Rooms (larger details filter),
Green - Details such as windows, doors, smaller rooms (smaller filter)

[image: example result]

Link to code for creating image : [Floorplan to Blender3d](https://github.com/grebtsew/FloorplanToBlender3d/blob/master/Examples/Development/find_walls_and_floor_and_rooms.py)
This project is a work in progress.